# Contar datos en un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este dataframe con 954 filas en R.

Necesito contar, para cada `Player.Name`, las veces que aparece una "P" o "G" en las columnas E1, E2, E3 y E4.

Entiendo que en primer lugar tengo que utilizar la función `group_by(Player.Name)` para que luego al contar me devuelva el resultado para cada caso de esa variable.

```
     Eventos = Eventos %>%
                group_by(Player.Name)
```

Despues intenté usar la función `count()` para contar las veces que aparece, y `grepl()` para indicar que tiene que tener "P" o "G". Sin embargo, no pude resolverlo.

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

Con `grepl()` puedes saber si determinado caracter se encuentra en una cadena, como el retorno es lógico y estos se transforman en 1 y 0 cuando los trabajamos de forma aritmética, solo nos restaría sumar los verdaderos:

```
library(tidyverse)

Eventos %>% 
  mutate(found_in_E1 = grepl('[PG]', E1),
         found_in_E2 = grepl('[PG]', E2),
         found_in_E3 = grepl('[PG]', E3),
         found_in_E4 = grepl('[PG]', E4)) %>% 
  group_by(Player.Name) %>% 
  summarise(found_in_E1 = sum(found_in_E1),
            found_in_E2 = sum(found_in_E2),
            found_in_E3 = sum(found_in_E3),
            found_in_E4 = sum(found_in_E4))
```

O, si lo preferís, una forma menos literal y más genérica:

```
selected_cols <- c('E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4')

Eventos %>% 
  mutate_at(selected_cols,
            ~grepl('[PG]', .)) %>% 
  group_by(Player.Name) %>% 
  summarise_at(selected_cols, sum)
```